# How to do Box-Cox transorm by group with Caret package in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to do Box-Cox transform for Iris dataset. I did as follows:

```
library(caret)
dat=iris[,1:4]
label=iris[,5]
model_boxcox=preProcess(dat,method="BoxCox")
dat_pre=predict(model_boxcox,dat)
```

Now, I want to use Box-Cox transform for each group in Species. How can I do?

Comment: This type of transformation is not going to get you far since when you predict you will need to transform the features of the new data for which you do not know the group, so you will not know which transformation to apply.

Comment: @ missuse: Thank you for explanation. I got this fact yesterday when I made prediction in "predict step".